# How to delete label after some event in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, label, textlabel

I have an application in which the images(created using Label(root,image='my_image)) change whenever some event occurs. Buttons are not used. One of my image has a label having text above an image. So it occurs where i want it. But when i move to next image after that, it is still there and i don't want it. What can i do? I have tried to destroy() the text label but it says that the variable is used before assignment.
Here is the part where i insert a text label. The panel2 variable doesn't work outside if block so i am not able to destroy it:

```
if common.dynamic_data:
        to_be_displayed = common.dynamic_data
        panel2 = tk.Label(root, text = to_be_displayed, font=("Arial 70 bold"), fg="white", bg="#9A70D4")
        panel2.place(x=520,y=220)
```

Comment: Store your Labels inside an array

Comment: Why don't you create that label on program start, then update its text based on the value of `common.dynamic_data`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on the canvas. Place label on the canvas and use `bind` functions for `Enter` and `Leave` events:

```
# imports
import tkinter as tk

# creating master
master = tk.Tk()

# hover functions
def motion_enter(event):
    my_label.configure(fg='green')
    print('mouse entered the canvas')

def motion_leave(event):
    my_label.configure(fg='grey')
    print('mouse left the canvas')

# create canvas, on which if you hover something happens
canvas = tk.Canvas(master, width=100, height=100, background='grey')
canvas.pack(expand=1, fill=tk.BOTH)

# create label
my_label = tk.Label(canvas, text='Toggle text is here!', fg='grey')
my_label.pack()

# binding enter and leave functions
master.bind('<Enter>', motion_enter)
master.bind('<Leave>', motion_leave)

# set window size
master.geometry('400x200')

# start main loop
master.mainloop()
```

You can change what configuration any objects have when you hovering canvas or anything else in created functions. Play with objects and code to do whatever you want to.

Also as it was mentioned you can store your labels or other objets in the list or dictionary to change separate objects, for exaple:

```
# imports
import tkinter as tk

# creating master
master = tk.Tk()

d = {}

# hover functions
def motion_enter(event):
    d['first'].configure(fg='green')
    print('mouse entered the canvas')

def motion_leave(event):
    d['first'].configure(fg='grey')
    print('mouse left the canvas')

# create canvas, on which if you hover something happens
canvas = tk.Canvas(master, width=100, height=100, background='grey')
canvas.pack(expand=1, fill=tk.BOTH)

# create label
my_label = tk.Label(canvas, text='Toggle text is here!', fg='grey')
my_label.pack()
d['first'] = my_label
my_label = tk.Label(canvas, text='Toggle text is here!', fg='grey')
my_label.pack()
d['second'] = my_label

# binding enter and leave functions
master.bind('<Enter>', motion_enter)
master.bind('<Leave>', motion_leave)

# set window size
master.geometry('400x200')

# start main loop
master.mainloop()
```

**EDIT 1**

If you want to remove label when the mouse left the canvas you can write such a functions:

```
def motion_enter(event):
    d['first'].pack()
    d['second'].pack()
    print('mouse entered the canvas')

def motion_leave(event):
    d['first'].pack_forget()
    d['second'].pack_forget()
    print('mouse left the canvas')
```

or just add 2 rows in the previous to combine them.

Comment: will it destroy the label after the image changes?